# Tomcat 8 How to set multiple instances on IIS

Tags: jsp, tomcat, iis, iis-7.5, tomcat8

I'm running two instances of Tomcat on a same machine, different IP (same NIC), and I'm having difficulty on configuring IIS to properly redirect traffic to the correct instance of Tomcat. I am able to connect to both instances without any issue locally from my server, but can only connect to one of them remotely.

From [documentation here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html), it seems like all I need to do is set up two different workers pointing to different AJP ports. Here's what my workers.properties.minimal file looks like:

```
worker.ajp13w.type=ajp13
#NOT AN ACTUAL IP
worker.ajp13w.host=10.7.7.7 
worker.ajp13w.port=8009
#NOT AN ACTUAL IP
worker.testsrvw.host=10.7.7.8
worker.testsrvw.host=8010
worker.testsrvw.type=ajp13
```

And here's what my uriworkermap.properties look like

```
/*.jsp=ajp13w    
/*.do=ajp13w
/*.action=ajp13w
/Content/*=ajp13w
/ContentTest/*=testsrvw
```

I can connect to ajp13w (10.7.7.7) without any issue, but I cannot connect to testsrvw (10.7.7.8). Instead of displaying a tomcat-related error, it displays an IIS error: **HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found**, indicating that the page is not being served from Tomcat.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any concise examples on how to host two instances of Tomcat under IIS?